# Differential Equations Questions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working through some questions we've been set over this period and there are two in particular which I am really struggling on how to work out. The first section I am confused completely on what to do and the second section is worth 7 marks so my working seems to simple. The question reads as follows:

A zoologist models a disease which is spreading through a colony of rabbits. The zoologist assumes that the rate of increase of the number of rabbits infected is
proportional to the product of the number of rabbits infected and the number not yet infected. At time t days, x is the number of rabbits infected. The zoologist estimates that:

-there are 5000 rabbits in the colony

-initially the number of infected rabbits is 200 
initially the disease is spreading at a rate of 50 rabbits per day.

Use the zoologist’s assumptions to answer the following questions.

i) Show that
$$({1\over x} + {1\over 5000-x}) {dx\over dt} =q$$

where q is a constant to be found Fully justify your answer.

ii)Find the length of time it takes for half of the rabbits to be infected

Comment: What is your effort?

Comment: What's the problem? How to derive to that ODE or how to solve it?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis My problem is how to solve it

Comment: By separating the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Break down the question step-by-step. It's important to approach these questions one step at a time.

We take $x$ as the number of infected rabbits, and $t$ as time. The question first states $$\text{"$\color{red}{\text{the rate of increase of inf rabbits}}$ is $\color{blue}{\text{proportional}}$ to the $\color{purple}{\text{product of rabbits infected and those not infected}"}$}$$

Using that there are $5000$ rabbits, mathematically, this reads as:

$$\color{red}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\color{blue}{=q}\color{purple}{x(5000-x)}$$

Can you use the "initially" conditions to determine $q$?

Comment: Many thanks for you hint, but may you be able to elaborate a bit further? The highlighting of the question has really helped but (and I know this may sound a bit stupid) I'm struggling to see how to correctly implement the 'initially' conditions into $$dx\over dt$$

Comment: "Initially" means the time $t=0$. It tells you "initially the # inf rabbits is $200$ (i.e. $t=0\to x=200$) and the initial rate is $50$ (i.e. $t=0\to \frac{dx}{dt}=50$)